# How to manually change one note to be displayed as "e flat" instead of "d sharp" in Guitar Pro 7?

Tags: guitar-pro

I want to change a single note to be displayed as "e flat" instead of "d sharp" in the score sheet below. Is it possible to adjust this in Guitar Pro 7 without changing the key signature (currently set to G Major)?

[image: score sheet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several options :

- Ctrl+Alt+8
- Menu Note -> Accidentals -> Change accidental
- This button on the left panel : [image]